# Adding file to jar during maven build

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

I am trying to add a license file to all of my jars when executing a maven build. I have the license on each class file, but I am looking to add License.txt to each META-INF folder within each jar

My project has a master pom, which has half dozen modules, those modules then have modules of their own, and eventually get to a project that generates a /target/<.jar-file>. The build and the class level licenses are working, I am just looking to add a physical License.txt into the META-INF folder.

My file is stored (relative to the master POM) in /src/resources/src-license.txt. I really need the automated method to ensure that if/when the license changes, I dotn have to update 50 files, I can just update the one, which is then copied out to the other locations.

I have tried using

```
<build>
  <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
  <resources>
    <resource>
      <directory>src/resources</directory>
      <targetPath>/META-INF</targetPath>
      <includes>
        <include>src-license.txt</include>
      </includes>
    </resource>
  </resources>
....
</build>
```

But that doesnt seem to do the trick. I have also tries some alternatives to the output path, such as ${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF, or */META_INF, also to no avail. Does anyone have some experience on how to accomplish this? Thanks

Also, I use the maven-license-plugin to ensure that each class file has the license info pasted into it, and that functions as intended. But again, that inside the class files, I am looking for an external .txt file in each <*.jar>/META-INF/

Comment: You have an multimodule project with a `src-license.txt` in parent project. You want to copy it to all submodule jars. Right?

Comment: yes. that is accurate. I want that license file to appear in the META-INF folder of every generated jar

Comment: It seems that path `src/resources` is invalid for submodules. Try using something like that `${project.parent.relativePath}/src/resources`.

Comment: No dice. I also tried ${baseDir}/src/resource and combinations between my previous META-INF iterations above.  Ive still been looking for a solution, and even the maven page seems pretty straight forward on the subject. http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Build_Settings I just cant find the magical combination

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using resources from parent relativePath is at least difficult (what if you have a complex directory structure?).

A simple and clean way can be to create a separate module containing your src-license.txt file. Then make it a dependency of your modules and unzip it (dependency:unpack-dependencies) @ generate-resources phase, inside target/classes.

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>unpack-license</id>
                <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                <goals><goal>unpack</goal></goals>
                <configuration>
                    <artifactItems>
                        <artifactItem>
                            <groupId>com.acme</groupId>
                            <artifactId>com.acme.license</artifactId>
                            <version>${project.version}</version>
                        </artifactItem>
                    </artifactItems>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I gave it a whirl, but to no avail. I was able get a new module with the license in it. And add it as a dependency, however the process to unpack the dependencies is where I stumbled. During the build, maven extracted files, but they all went to either the target/dependencies or target/classes rather then the final .jar, I wasnt able to find a way to inject the one file I need into the jar either.

Comment: If the license ends up inside target/classes, *before* the package phase, that would be sufficient. Something like I just set in my answer should work.

Comment: Alright. First thanks to Tome. I retried this approach after the long weekend and got it working! I was definitely not doing the phase portions correctly. Maven still baffles me, but I learn more and more all the time.  I did add a /META-INF to the output directory tags just to get the file sorted. And my source bundle for the file needed to resource tags.  All in all, it sorted itself out fairly well. Again, Thanks

Comment: P.S. I would up-vote you, but I don't have the privileged yet.