# How include license to jar file in android library (aar)

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, license-maven-plugin

I Have aar project and I want to add license to jar file.
I add licence to .pom file, but I want add it to jar and get structure like this:

[image]
Is it possible add `LICENSE.txt` to `.jar` by gradle?

Answer (score 0):

if you want add LICENSE.txt into your android library (aar). you should do two  things:

1. add your LICENSE.txt to your project, path: src/main/resources/META-INF(other resources folders are acceptable as well)
2. add "android {packagingOptions{ merge '**/LICENSE.txt'}" into your xxx(sdkname)/build.gradle file.

the keyword merge means add all matching files to your aar

Answer (score -1):

here is the `jar` document describes:

> JAR file is a file format based on the popular ZIP file format and is used for aggregating many files into one. A  JAR file is essentially a zip file that contains an optional META-INF directory

the `META_INF` function is that:

> The META-INF directory, if it exists, is used to store package and extension configuration data, including security, versioning, extension, and services.

so I think you should put it int the `META_INF` files. you can see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37655114/5705408) get some solution.

Comment: How I can add LICENSE.txt to .jar in gradle?

Comment: @Nikolay, see this answer[https://stackoverflow.com/a/18533986/5705408].